# Is henotheism also a sin in Islam?

Tags: shirk, jinn

We all know that Islam is a monotheistic religion condemning idol worship/polytheism by calling it the greatest of all sins . But what about henotheism? In henotheism, God is one with multiple demigods/deities (like Angel Gabriel and jinns). Is believing in henotheism also a sin?

Comment: I am not sure what you require here. You are giving your own non-standard definitions of [henotheism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/henotheism) , and [dieties](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/god) and asking if Islam accepts that premise. Angels and jinns are not *deities* or *demigods*, they are creation, they are subservient, they have no independent authority or power, nor the ability to aid or harm unless Allah commands them, they aren't worshiped, nor invoked nor supplicated to.

Comment: If you are going to define a demigod as anything with "abilities" that humans don't, then yes, just as there are birds that can fly, fish that can breathe underwater, snakes that can see in the dark, horses that can run faster, camels that are stronger.

Comment: @Uma "Demigods" in Hinduism also have no independent authority. They are all commanded by one God.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are the Islamic beliefs about God:

> لا إله إلا الله
>
> *There is no god, except Allah*  <sup>[47:19](https://quran.com/47/19)</sup>
>
> الله أحد
>
> *Allah is One*<sup>[112:1](https://quran.com/112/1)</sup>
>
> وحده لا شريك له
>
> *He is Alone, and has no partners or associates*<sup>[6:163](https://quran.com/6/163) , [Hadith](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=%22%D9%88%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%87%20%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%83%20%D9%84%D9%87%22)</sup>
>
> لا حول ولا قوة إلا بالله
>
> *There is no Might or Power, except Allah*<sup>[18:39](https://quran.com/18/39), [Hadith](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=%22%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84%20%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A9%20%D8%A5%D9%84%D8%A7%20%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%22)</sup>
>
> ان كل من في السماوات والارض الا اتي الرحمـن عبدا
>
> *There is no one in the heavens and earth but that he comes to the Most
> Merciful as a servant*.<sup>[19:93](https://quran.com/19/93)</sup>
>
> انني انا الله لا الـه الا انا فاعبدني واقم الصلاة لذكري
>
> In*deed, I am Allah . There is no deity except Me, so worship Me and establish prayer for My remembrance.*  <sup>[20:14](https://quran.com/20/14)</sup>

Any belief that contradict the above is called *shirk* and is the greatest sin<sup>[4:116](https://quran.com/4/116)</sup>. *Henotheism* is the worship of one God, without rejecting the existence of others and this is *shirk* as well.

Comment: What does the second last verse mean?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury that all things in sky and earth are servants of god.

Comment: @qdinar r these things deities that are servants of God?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury It means every creature, angels, animals, jinn, humans, hoors, aliens, the planets and stars, the Prophets, Jesus etc. Its a negation of *shirk* beliefs that other religions had and have.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury there is phrase/word "la ilaha illa llah" in islam, according to it that "deities" should not be regarded as deities, except allah.